# add var to array object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Yesterday I received some help looping through my var arr and search the system for .png files. with the following code:

```
 const fs = require('fs');
 const path = require('path');
 const imageDir = '/var/scraper/public/images/flags/';

 var filesExist = arr.map((imgObj) => {
   const imgfile = imgObj.country;
   let filePath = path.join(imageDir, imgfile + ".png");
   //console.log('Checking existance of file: ', filePath);
   return { Logopath: fs.existsSync(filePath) ? filePath: path.join(imageDir, "noimage.png")};
});

console.log(filesExist);
```

Which is working fine, However at the end of my server.js file (not included here) I write all of the data from the var arr into mongodb for later access.

I would also need to write the data that is stored in the new var filesExist  into mongodb. So I think the best solution is to just to add data from filesExist  into the var arr.

After reading through some google search I tried something this

```
arr["Logopath"] = filesExist;
```

but this is not working

I also tried this

```
arr.unshift({
    Logopath: filesExist
});
```

Which is semi working but this increases the size of the array and inputs alot of undefined values into it.

How can I add the data from var filesExist info to arr["Logopath"]?

Comment: You appear to be confusing arrays with objects. They are not the same thing.   Your first attempt treats "arr" as an object. The second attempt treats it as an array which contains objects.  (And as far as I can tell, filesExist is reading its information from arr in the first place, so it's not clear what you intend by adding that data back into arr?)

Comment: When you `console.log(filesExist)`, what do you see? You *should* see an array of objects, each of which has a property `Logopath` that is set to a file path. Why do you want to add this to `arr`? What are you going to do with this data? This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)...

Comment: Hi in console It returns the file path ,  when I do console.log  filesExist.length it returns around 300 or so

Comment: @ Daniel Beck yes you are right im confusing them. I really want the data from filesExist into arr["Logopath"] = filesExist;

Comment: @ Mike McCaughan, Hi this is not an xy problem. I have all my data stored in the arr var and It would be great to have the file path stored in the same var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `imgObj.Logopath = '...'`.

It's not `arr["Logopath"]` you want, but `arr[i]["Logopath"]` for every `i`. And `imgObj` is `arr[0]` then `arr[1]` and so on.

`forEach` would be more approprate than `map` in this case.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply .,  yes I want each row in the logopath into my arr. Do you mind showing an sample as i'm not exactly sure how I would go about this

Answer (score 0):

Im gonna answer my own question here, but I want to thank **Ben West** for pointing me in the right direction:

```
for (var i = 0; i < filesExist.length; i++) {
    arr[i]["Logopath"] = filesExist[i]
}
```

Works for me...